# TSQL error on JDBC call "Incorrect syntax near '@P1"

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

The "Incorrect syntax near '@P1" from a TSQL stored procedure seems to be a common issue but none of the advice that I have seen has solved my problem.   My query works in SQL Management Server Studio is not working from my JDBC code.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get-ErrorLogByWorkflowId] (
       @workflowId AS NVARCHAR(255) -- removed second parameter to simplify: , BIGINT @numSecondsOfErrors=300
)
AS
BEGIN
...
```

This is the Java code using JDBC that I use to call the stored procedure:

```
CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("{ call dbo.Get-ErrorLogByWorkflowId(?) }");
stmt.setString(1, workflowId);
//second parameter removed to simplify call: stmt.setLong(2, seconds);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

I have tried calling the stored procedure both with and without brackets, e.g., [dbo][Get-...].  I have also tried declaring the parameter both as a VARCHAR and NVARCHAR.  What should I do to correct this?

Note: I had previously observed some odd problems handling names beginning with "Get-", but the prefix is part of my company's standards and I eventually got such queries to work.

Comment: I don't know Java but just an observation, should the parameter value be passed as a "string" ie quoted?

Comment: @Stu: no, not at all. Putting the `?` in quotes would not fix the problem.

Comment: The name of your stored procedure in your T-SQL and your JDBC code are different (there's no `AMS` in your JDBC code). Is this a transcription error or a genuine problem?

Comment: Regardless of whether your proc is called `Get-AMSErrorLogByWorkflowId` or `Get-ErrorLogByWorkflowId` it contains a non-token character, `-`, and needs to be bracket quoted, e.g.: `dbo.[Get-ErrorLogByWorkflowId]`

Comment: @LukeWoodward The names actually match in the code.  I took out the AMS in the posting as an identifying mark.  I will edit for that.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have tried with both with and without brackets but will retry it.  If it solves the problem I would be happy to credit you with the answer.  I had noticed without brackets it would error on the text after the dash

Answer (score 0):

@AlwayLearning was correct.  Uniformly using brackets around the portions of the names of the stored procedure worked - so I now use [dbo].[Get-ErrorLogByWorkflowId] to be on the safe side